# Como colocar dois botões um do lado do outro

Tags: html, css, button, inline

Não entendo tanto de HTML e CSS quanto gostaria e preciso fazer uma pequena mudança num site em que eu estou limitadíssimo, dai fiz isso aqui.

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style="float: right; border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Abra sua conta</a></div>
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style="float: center; border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Minha conta</a></div>
</div>
<p>
```

Os botões ficam ok só que fica um sobreposto ao outro, e eu preciso que fique um do lado do outro. Alguém pode me ajudar com uma solução para isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocar isso dentro de uma **table** deve funcionar:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style="float: right; border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Abra sua conta</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style="float: center; border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Minha conta</a>
            </div>
        </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal mesmo é continuar utilizando div's. Tire os estilos *float* dos botões e adicione um estilo as suas div's.

```css
.floatLeft{float:left};
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <a class="button floatLeft" href="(LINK)" style="border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Abra sua conta</a></div>
    <div>
        <a class="button floatLeft" href="(LINK)" style="border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Minha conta</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu. =)

Comment: Marca como resposta! Dessa forma ajudará outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Jovem primeiramente `Float:center` **não existe!** Só temos o `Float:left` e `Float:right` Documentação sobre o [Float no CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Mas a minha resposta não usa nenhum dos dois *(retire os floats)*. Para resolver o seu problema basta coloca `display:inline-block` nas `div`

```css
div > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style=" border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Abra sua conta</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="(LINK)" style=" border:1px solid; padding: 11px 21px; vertical-align: middle; background:#2D888F; color:white;border-radius:6px; font-size: 20px; font-family:helvetica, serif;text-decoration:none;">Minha conta</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, pelo que percebi tem mais de um jeito pra resolver isso. Acabei usando essa solução por ser mais simples. Valeu.

Comment: Ok Bruno, eu gosto dessa solução pq com float:left vc pode ter problemas com outros elementos na página. Se vc optou pela minha resposta basta marca-la como aceita nesse icone `✔` a baixo das setinhas da minha resposta. Evite deixar perguntas que já foram resolvidas como abertas no site. Boa sorte com o projeto!

Comment: Valeu brother, não sabia que eu precisava marcar a setinha... hehe... como eu "fecho" a pergunta??

Comment: @BrunoSilva na verdade vc só pode aceitar `✔` uma Resposta. Então seria legal vc sempre sinalizar a resposta que vc realmente usou no final das contas. Quando vc aceita a resposta o site já deixa ela como "resolvida" isso impede que ela volte para fila de "Perguntas sem Resposta" por isso é bom Sinalizar (fechar) a Pergunta aceitando uma resposta `✔` quando ela já foi resolvida. É meio confuso, mas acho que deu para entender né.